# Does this question need protection?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

[This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/how-can-i-improve-this-series-of-if-else-statements) is starting to attract new users who contribute nothing more than "use a `switch` statement" as an answer.  One of these answers is also a copy cat of previous answers.  There really is no need for these additional answers, especially because this is already mentioned *and demonstrated* in some top answers.  If those new users have nothing new to contribute, then I don't think those answers should remain.  Even with the downvotes, they're just creating noise.

If any 3500+ users agree, someone please consider protecting that question.  If those low-quality answers need not remain, then trusted users (4K+) could cast delete votes.  On the other hand, [having enough answers from new users deleted will automatically cause the Community User to protect the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers).  I've also flagged a moderator in case further action here is uncertain.

Comment: I flagged it as such about an hour ago.

Comment: @retailcoder: Very good. :-) More flags mean that more people agree.

Comment: Indeed. Actually the last couple noise answers we all from 1-rep users... protecting it would definitely help.

Comment: @retailcoder: Right.  What about that copycat answer (if you've noticed)?  It's also from a 1-rep user.  I couldn't find too much info about such answers on MSO.

Comment: Noise, should be deleted along with the rest of the noise.

Comment: @retailcoder: I've mentioned all of that in the flag, so each offending answer should be deleted.  I didn't flag each individual question so as to avoid flag-whoring.

Comment: with a duplicate answer, I have flagged such answers on SO before using the `other` option, and they were deleted by a Moderator

Comment: @Malachi: That's what I also consider, same with link-only answers.  I just try not to do it too often if it doesn't seem that bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree, and have enabled protection.